# PHP Arrays Values

Tags: php, arrays

Please provide help on how to write array values if I have array like this:

```
    Array ( 
      [937245328] => $0.79 
      [310776983] => $0.53 
      [720315389] => $0.39 
      [310800933] => $0.30 
      [1011934667] => $0.28 
      [1576813623] => $0.21 
      [926978479] => $0.19 
      [1011934570] => $0.14 
      [937244096] => $0.14 
      [310777321] => $0.13 
      [384801319] => $0.13 
      [519987816] => $0.12 
      [992123310] => $0.11 
)
```

I would like to print this array out somelike this:

```
937245328: $0.79
310776983: $0.53
720315389: $0.39
```

and so on... Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you want to create array using php for above array?

Comment: A simple foreach loop?!

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` Refer to manuals: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thank you all, it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your array is called

```
$myArray
```

Then you can print it out as follows:

```
<?php
  foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
  {
    echo $key.": ".$value."<br>";
  }
?>
```

Let me know if that worked for you! :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, i have actually already tried it but I had probably a syntax error so i thought it was a wrong way to do it...

Comment: @Hugo No problem! If the answer solved your issue, please accept it with a green check mark so that future users know it worked :)

Comment: I know but there is a time limit while I cannot do it, i wanted to do it, don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the array (the key and the value) using `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
$dolla = Array ( 
      '937245328' => '$0.79',
      '310776983' => '$0.53',
      '720315389' => '$0.39'
);
foreach($dolla as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.": ".$value."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.